# How to check whether a html tag visible or hidden in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I've a div which I want to check whether it's hidden or not, and I wonder if there's way to do that in angular 2?

Comment: You could add a template variable to that div and see if it'ts present using ViewChild from angular/core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a variable to hide or show it, you can use that same variable to check whether is hidden or shown. For example, in this template

```
<div ng-if="showdiv">my div</div>
```

to know if this div is being shown, inside a controller just use

```
if ($scope.showdiv)
  // is shown
else
  // is hidden
```

(Note: this is for angular1, not sure if the same applies in angular2)